# Access 2013 Linked table timeout error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have an application in Access 2013 in which I create a linked table via ODBC. Linked table connects to SQL Server in the backend. After I create a linked table, when I double click on it (in order to view the table in a datasheet view), I get following error:

> ODBC Call Failed
>
> [Microsoft][SQL Native Client] Query timeout expired(#0)

I researched online but haven't found any useful information (there were few posts that mentioned about changing the query timeout value to 0 in Windows registry however, I am not executing any query here so I don't know how to change the timeout value for a linked table).

Comment: how much data do you have in table that you are trying to access?

Comment: I have about 88000 records in a table

Answer (score 1):

The old trick is to have one form bound to any table of the server. Then open this form hidden when launching the application and let it remain open.

This should establish a create-alive connection to the server preventing it from timing out.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your OLE/DDE timeout setting in access options:

[image: Access Options]

I've found that the most stable and reliable way to get Microsoft Access to use SQL Server as a back end is to create a Microsoft Access Project file (.ADP).

Comment: Thanks but it still didn't help. I bumped up the timeout value to 3000.

Comment: Is there a lock on the table maybe?  Can you query the table from another session in Management Studio?  How long does it run before you get the timeout message?  I'm not really sure what governs the timeout on linked tables... I usually use Access Project Files, which are much more stable for using access as a front end to a SQL Server database.

Comment: I am not sure whether there is a lock on the table or not. As mentioned, it is a linked table in Access (with SQL server in the back end).. It runs for about 2 mins before timing out.

Answer (score 0):

In my version of Access 2016, The ODBC timeout is in Client Settings.  (File -> Options -> Client Settings).  I do not have the Advanced option mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

On the property sheet for your query, try setting the ODBC Timeout=0.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an Oracle backend. Changing the ODBC settings fixed it for me.
Refer to this link https://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/101855

Answer (score -1):

You could try converting the linked table to a pass through query (`SELECT * FROM ....`) as you can set a time out on a passthrough.