# Set commandtimeout for linked SQL Tables/Views in Access front end

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, odbc

We have moved some back-end data tables over from a network drive (mbd file) to being on an SQL Server database.  Things mostly work great, but if staff are accessing things through a VPN (which slows things down a lot), then we get connection errors when we run reports that retrieve a lot of data.  My guess is that I need to set a timeout to a larger value, and I did some research and it seems that I need to set the commandtimeout (or maybe query timeout?).

Below is the VBA code we use to connect the SQL Server tables/views to our Access front end from the SQL Server back end.  Am I right that I likely need to specify a commandtimeout?  Where in this would we add the commandtimeout (or other timeout) value?

```vb
Public Sub CreateSQLLinkedTable(strSourceTableName As String, strNewTableName As String)

'************************************************************************************
'* Create a linked table in the current database from a table in a different SQL Server file.
'* In:                                                                              *
'*   strNewTableName - name of linked table to create                               *
'*   strSourceTableName - name of table in database                             *
'************************************************************************************

Setup:

    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim strConnect As String, strMsg As String
    Dim myDB As Database

    ' set database vars
    Set myDB = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = myDB.CreateTableDef(strNewTableName)

MakeConnections:

    On Error GoTo OnError

    ' turn system warnings off
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    ' define connect string and source table
    ' We do not need to specify the username (Uid) and password (Pwd) in this connection
    ' string, because that information is already cached from the connection to the SQL
    ' Projects database that we created in CheckSQLConnection() that was run to check connection
    ' to the database.  So here we can have a connection string without the Uid and Pwd.
    With tdf
        .Connect = "ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};" & _
                  "server=" & myServer & ";" & _
                  "database=" & mySQLDB & ";"

        .SourceTableName = strSourceTableName
    End With

    ' execute appending the table
    myDB.TableDefs.Append tdf

    ' turn system warnings back on
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

ExitProgram:
    ' this block of code will run if there are no errors

    Exit Sub

OnError:
    ' this block of code runs if there is an error, per On Error assignment above

    ' display error message with details
    MsgBox "There was an error connecting to the SQL Server data source Projects. Error = " & err & ", Description: " & err.Description

    'exit Projects
    Call CloseFormsAndQuit

End Sub
```

Comment: Access uses a single timeout value for all linked tables. To change it, view [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604158). You can set a timeout for each table, though.

Comment: In the long (or not so long) run, you should look into moving some or all of the data processing to the server - using more elaborate views or stored procedures - so that less data has to be passed to the client.

Comment: Making our queries pass-through (and otherwise optimizing stuff) is definitely next on the to-do list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an ODBC timeout property. Open the query in design view, and go to properties to see it. There is also an (ODBC) query timeout on the current database properties page. You can set it programmatically as well:

```
Dim objDB As DAO.Database
Set objDB = CurrentDb()
objDB.QueryTimeout = 120
```

http://www.geeksengine.com/article/how-to-change-timeout-value-for-access-sql.html
Also check the server configuration. There is a query timeout on server side.

Comment: That worked.  We also had the server admin set the server configuration.  Thanks...